# Delete expired cron jobs from crontab

Tags: linux, cron

My product requires a cronjob processing for every message a user sends to another users. This cronjob gets added to the crontab on the server. Everything works fine. Now once the job is done, is there a way to remove the expired cronjob entry from `crontab`?

Since the number of messages are huge, my crontab keeps growing so I want to clean up the old job entries. Any neat way of achieving it?

Comment: If it were me, and this were an option, I'd move all this processing into a different script and just have cron call that script, rather than messing about with tons of cronjob entries. That just sounds like a recipe for pain.

Comment: Agree with Christian Ternus.  If the processing job has to be scheduled for some time in the future, in may be better to use `at` rather than cron.  `at` is better suited for scheduling a one-time job for some time in the future, whereas `cron` is better suited for jobs that need to be executed repeatedly.  `at` jobs will 'disappear' from the schedule automatically after they are executed.

Answer (score 0):

At least in most Linux distributions there is a [crontab](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab) command that allows you to fetch and set the contents for the user's `crontab`. You can use it as such:

```
crontab -l > myfile
... edit the file (removing the entry)
crontab myfile
```

However this is clunky and error-prone. A better way is to wrap your job in a script that checks for a condition (e.g. a flag file) to decide whether to run the underlying logic and manipulate this flag file instead.